# Discord Python - Is there a way to make a bot read commands from another bot, or do we have to change the whole thing to on_message event?

Tags: python, discord

**We want to make one of our bots run commands when our other bot calls them (writes them in chat).**

We currently use the current structure, that doesn't react to commands made from other bots:

```
@self.client.command(pass_context = True)
async def play(ctx, channel, url):
    #Execute command
```

In order to make our bot read commands from another bot, do we have to change it to this?:

```
@self.client.event  
async def on_message(message):
    #Execute command
```

Or is there some way to make our bot execute commands that are made from another bot?

Comment: You would have to use `on_message`  events, yes.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the command before the check if the author is a bot, try this format

```
@client.event 
async def on_message(message):

    if message.content == '!ex1':
        # Message without bot check
        await message.channel.send('You could be a bot!')

    if message.author == client.user:
        return # Don't respond if the author is a bot

    if message.content == '!ex2':
        # Message with bot check
        await message.channel.send('You are a user!')
```